# Deploy Java application on MacOSX (from a Windows system)

Tags: java, deployment, swt

Here's the deal. I'm just starting with Java programming, I've made a simple application that uses SWT graphic library and I want to deploy it on a Mac (running the latest version of MacOS X).
I did all the programming in my Windows 7 machine, so here are my questions:

**Q1) Can I make an executable file for MacOS X from my Windows machine? How?** (I saw that it's possible to create .exe files on Windows, instead of using .jar; I want to do the same for the Mac, of course it won't be an .exe)

**Q2)** If I export my project in Eclipse and I choose `Runnable JAR File` and then on `Library Handling` I pick `Extract required libraries into generated JAR` or `Package required libraries into generated JAR` **I end up with a huge .JAR (about 15MB of size, my application consist in just a button on a Window and a tiny method that doesn't do much). Is that considered normal?**
Here's the list of libraries that my project appears to be using:

[image]

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: You have to bundle the jar inside an  application bundle, there is [this](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html) tutorial directly from Apple..

Q2: Yes, it's 15mb because all the referenced libraries that does not reside inside the **JRE System Library** are included inside the final jar. There are different approaches:

- bundle all together like you are doing
- bring other **.jars** together with yours without packing them
- install the jar separately, they must be copied once into **$JAVA_HOME/lib/ext** and then every application on the same JRE will have them

Comment: Thanks. BTW, about the 15mb file, I realized that there were a lot of unused libraries, after removing all and just leaving SWT I got a 1.4mb file :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to export an application to multiple platforms, install the Eclipse Delta pack on you development machine. Here's a [tutorial](http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-deltapack-in-eclipse-35.html). After you install it, you can export your eclipse application to any target (Windows, Linux, OSX, etc).

EDIT: Here's another [tutorial](http://ugosan.org/eclipse-rcp-delta-pack/).

Comment: Thanks for replying. It's not that easy though, can you point me to a good tutorial or documentation on how to use that? (Installation was the easy part)

Comment: Actually, it's all in there. When you export your product with the eclipse export wizard (to generate the *.exe file), just check "export to multiple platfroms" in the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself some grief and convert your eclipse project to a maven project and then use the OSX App Bundle plugin:  http://mojo.codehaus.org/osxappbundle-maven-plugin/ .  Maven projects are easily loaded in eclipse through either the use of `mvn eclipse:eclipse` or by using the m2 plugin.

If you need to build for both Windows and OSX, set up two different build profiles in your maven pom.xml to call the appropriate bundler.