# How to change JavaFx native Bundle exe icon

Tags: icons, bundle, native, javafx-2, exe

I am trying to chance the icon of the exe file created native bundling of javafx packaging but it still contains the default icon. Please suggest

```
 primaryStage.getIcons().add(FileUtility.loadImage("icon.png"));
```

did not help, it only changes the title bar and task bar icon.

[image: default icons]

The ico file still gets generated and icon of the exe files remains the default one

I also tried to assign an icon in the project properties-> Deployment-> icon but did not help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121991/javafx-2-application-icon

Comment: Yes, finally I moved to launch4j to create exe with icon

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for this: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_setupiconfile ? In order to produce the exe setup, one must use InnoSetup according to JavaFX docs and you can customize the icon in InnoSetup configuration using link I gave.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I have encountered the same issue and the solution is described in the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683335/including-an-icon-into-a-self-contained-javafx-application-exe) thread.

As a side note - neither specifying your icon in the **build.xml** file or via the project's options in the *deployment* section is going to work thus far, but it seems to be [fixed](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7) in the upcoming release of **7u10**.

Answer (score 0):

I added response here [How to set custom icon for javafx native package icon on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880102/how-to-set-custom-icon-for-javafx-native-package-icon-on-windows) and thinks it is the same issue you started out with. However you seem to have moved on, but others might find it interesting...

Comment: @Mateusz I don't know how to make a comment since I don't have that as an option - only `share | edit` is visible to me. Except on my own posts.

Answer (score 0):

I added src/main/deploy/package/windows/myapp.ico there and it finally worked :)

For you:

Create src/main/deploy/package/windows/ folder
Add icon with name ${project.build.finalName}.ico
Run mvn jfx:build-native
I haven't played with it extensively - just got it to work and wanted to share. So if you want to use icon with different name, I don't know how. Not yet at least. The ... section in the config section seems to be for webstart, so I haven't been using it. Hope you get it to work!

Answered at [How to set custom icon for javafx native package icon on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880102/how-to-set-custom-icon-for-javafx-native-package-icon-on-windows)