# JavaFX: How to create an application icon with notification badge?

Tags: java, javafx

How to create a notification app icon badge in JavaFX's taskbar icon? Just like Teams or Slack that has a badge on their icon when a notification comes.
Like this image:

[image]

Comment: IntelliJ offers a feature to add the programs icon image on building it, File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts + JavaFX

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237050/how-to-change-default-java-logo-exe-icon-on-the-taskbar-in-javafx

Comment: No I mean, like this one https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/pages/chart/slack/notification-icon.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific way to define icons with badges for JavaFX. However, you can change the icon of your application based on whether you have notifications or not:

```java
// define two (or more) different icons
Image iconWithNoNotifications = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("app_icon.png"));
Image iconWithNotifications = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("app_icon_with_notification.png"));

// change the icon when the notifications count changes
primaryStage.getIcons().add(nNotifications == 0 ? iconWithNoNotifications : iconWithNotifications);
```