# How can i set application icon in javafx2

Tags: icons, set, javafx-2

javafx set application ico

when i create java project , add jfxrt.jar

it's right

```
new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../images/customLogo.png"))
```

but this in javafx project

it's wrong.

how can i  get relative path do this in javafx project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should take a look on the [Image API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) and this another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121991/javafx-2-application-icon) where how to put the icon is answered.

If you were generating a jar, you can use

```
new Image("/path/to/image")
```

The path to the image starting with "/", will be an absolute path inside the jar. I strongly recommends go to the Image API to check all the options, is really well documented.

Hope it helps

Comment: api does not indicate how the relative path to access the image file superiors or their sibling directory only access subdirectories and absolute path access.

Comment: I think it does. Actually this fragment is extracted from the API: """ Construct a new Image with the specified parameters. The url without scheme is threated as relative to classpath, url with scheme is treated accordingly to the scheme using URL.openStream() """. So, the path that you are looking for is relative to your classpath, and where you are executing your application. http://goo.gl/FiEll

Answer (score 0):

So what is the exception? Where did you create the project (which IDE). As a general rule never use ..-paths when doing look ups although the might work on the filesystem they e.g. break inside jar-files IIRC.

Comment: netbeans 7.3 if change pic image to Subdirectory images  and  new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/customLogo.png")) is right

Comment: Right IIRC netbeans always creates a JAR of your application and runs it - this is why it doesn't work because when you are using ".." in paths!