# Set Icon on Stage in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, stagewebview

I wanted to know how should I set icons on javaFX stage.
I have found this method, but it did not work properly.

```
  stage.getIcons().add(new Image(iconImagePath));
```

stage is an instance of javafx.stage.Stage, and I have imported javafx.scene.image.Image.
This is the exception which we receive:

Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found

Also, there is nothing wrong with the iconImagePath, its value is "G:/test.jpg"
and there is a jpg file in the G drive named test. In addition, when we use ImageIO to read the same URL we can do it easily.

Comment: `G:/test.jpg` is not a URL, what if you try with `file:/G:/test.jpg`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121991/javafx-2-application-icon/10122335#10122335

Answer (score 18):

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("bal.png")));
```

This example works. I placed an icon in the same folder/package as the source .java file.

**Directory structure**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, using this method no exception will be thrown, but the image icon of stage has not changed!!

Comment: Thank you again, but it does not work with this path: file:images/pic.jpeg

Comment: if you use **getResourceAsStream("")** no need to **file:** . it is just a protocal. so remove the file: if you are using getResourceAsStream

Comment: Did as you said, but I receive this exception: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null

Comment: It was jpeg, I changed it to jpg, but it still is not working. What is this list of images on stage (stage.getIcons()), and what happens if someone adds to Image or more to it? I mean

Comment: stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("bal.png")));    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("bal2.png")));

Comment: look my answer. upload my directory structure. where .java file located there your image file  locate.

Comment: Yes Subash Your answer is correct its working fine. May be Siavash have some version specific problem or he has not clean and build project. I am agreed its working.

Comment: I am using Java 8 on eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Thank you in advance, I checked your solution and it worked, but I do not want to put my image file next to my .java files.

Comment: then where you want to put??

Comment: Because I have a lot of images, I have created a folder named images in the root of the project next to src and bin folders.

Comment: But it does not work!!! when I change the String "temp.jpeg" to "images/temp.jpeg" I get a null pointer exception which says inputstream must not be null.

Comment: Actually it should work, but it doesn't for me. I am running Ubuntu and got the same issue with Swing. I think it is somehow connected to the application icon cache. And I still don't know how to fix it. Clean and Build doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

The constructors of `javafx.scene.image.Image` expect a URI, not a (full) path. This URI can either be relative (e.g. `/images/flower.png`) or absolute (e.g. `file:flower.png`).

Strings like `G:/test.jpg` are no valid URLs and hence illegal.

Try `file:g:/test.jpg` instead.

Usually, the icons should be bundled with your application, so simply put the image file into your classpath (e.g. if you're using eclipse, put it into your 'src' directory) and use it like that:

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/logo.jpg"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, using this method no exception will be thrown, but the image icon of stage has not changed!!

Comment: It you don't get any exception, it means that the image could be found and loaded. You should see it in the trimming area of your window, the windows task bar and the task list if you press Alt+Tab.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(("file:logo.png")));
```

and put the image logo.png  in root of your project ( at same directory where src )

Comment: Thank you very much, using this method no exception will be thrown, but the image icon of stage has not changed!!

Comment: try to clean project and build it again not only run.

Comment: can you post your directory structure..?

Answer (score 2):

Best Way:

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResource(IconImagePath).toExternalForm()));
```

Comment: This is a little terse.  Please explain why this solution is the "best way", especially when there are so many other answers posted already.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget that your icon must be in `32x32` or `16x16` resolution, if not, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code, which is exactly what you neened:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Manikant gautam
 * This is a beginner's sample application
 * using JAVAFX
 * 
*/

public class Helloworld extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        // Set Icon From Here.
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(
            new Image("/resource/graphics/app_logo.png"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Set Icon by statement:

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/resource/graphics/app_logo.png"));
```

Comment: I thought it would be helpful by the help of example.Instead of putting a single line code.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Set the icon
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("penguin.png")));
```

I faced the same problem. I used Netbeans. I'm not sure if the folder structure is different for other IDEs, but I had to put the picture in /build/classes/(package that contains the JavaFX class file). This means it doesn't go into the src folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using eclipse make sure you add the folder that has the image to the build path. this way you can refer to the image with its name with no problems.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done and it work. The image is located in the root of my resource folder.

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/ubuntu-mini.png"));
```

I am using JavaFX 8

Answer (score 0):

I use netbeans 8.2, if I use :

```
stage.getIcons().addAll(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("home-icon32.png")));
```

I have to put the image in src directory. Don't know why, but works only this way. I've tried putting it in build/classes, but negative.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is:

```
File f = new File("image.png");
Image ix = new Image(f.toURI().toString());
stage.getIcons().add(ix);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
        {
            try
                {
                    // BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
                    BorderPane root = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader
                            .load(getClass().getResource("/org/geeksynergy/view/layout/FrontPageBorder.fxml"));
                    root.setAccessibleText("good");

                    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
                    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass()
                            .getResource("/org/geeksynergy/view/cssstyle/application.css").toExternalForm());
                    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                    primaryStage.setTitle("AiRJuke");
                    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/org/geeksymergy/resource/images/download.png"));
                    primaryStage.show();
                    AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader
                            .load(getClass().getResource("/org/geeksynergy/view/layout/Ui.fxml"));

                    root.setCenter(personOverview);

                    // added this line to save the playlist , when we close
                    // application window
                    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

                    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
                        {
                            public void handle(WindowEvent event)
                                {
                                    M3UPlayList.defaultSavePlaylist();
                                    Platform.setImplicitExit(true);
                                    primaryStage.hide();
                                }
                        });

                } catch (Exception e)
                {

                    LOGGER.error("Exception while loding application", e);
                }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            launch(args);
        }
}
```