# JavaFX 2 Window Icon not working

Tags: java, jar, icons, javafx-2, executable-jar

I'm trying to add an Icon to my JavaFX 2 application, but the ways I have found don't seem to work.

```
Image icon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/icon.png"));
stage.getIcons().add(icon);
```

The icon is 32x32 in size.

When I try

```
Image icon = new Image("http://goo.gl/kYEQl");
```

It does work, in Netbeans and in the runnable jar.

I hope this can be fixed.

Comment: Are you sure, your image is being loaded?

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, the resource stream is superfluous, and you can use the filepath directly. Anyways, make sure that the image exists in the location you have given again..

Comment: Yes, because when I remove the "/" in front of "images" or use "/images/icon2.png" I get a NullPointerException refering that the Inputstream cannot be null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094620/set-icon-on-stage-in-javafx/20094784#20094784

Comment: @subash I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to display the icon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was in the icon itself. It did load it like it should, but for some reason it didn't display like it should.

I remade the icon I was trying to use to different sizes (16x16 up to 512x512) and added them all to the icon list.

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/logo_16.png")));
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/logo_32.png")));
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/logo_64.png")));
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/logo_128.png")));
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/logo_256.png")));
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/logo_512.png")));
```

Now it uses the icon like it should.