# JavaFX: Adding Application-Icon with fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to add an application icon to my program. I've tried to do that as following, but it haven't worked:

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("lock.png")));
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Controller.class.getResourceAsStream("lock.png")));
    final Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("passwordGenerator.fxml"));
```

or

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("lock.png"));
```

Also I tried to do that without a `FXML` file and it worked.

**How can I add an application Icon with a `FXML` file?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX Application Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121991/javafx-application-icon)

Comment: Your image and your Main class are in the same package?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine This answer haven't worked for me

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine My image and Main class are in the same package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the solution it works with me :
Main class :

```
public class JavaFXIcons extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(JavaFXIcons.class.getResourceAsStream("stackoverflow.jpg"))) ;
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxicons.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```