# Jar file resource not found when building artifact

Tags: java, javafx, jar, exe, executable-jar

I am using intelliJ idea. I am using base path for accessing resources as follow:

```
String basePath = ".\\src\\main\\resources";
```

This is my project structure.

[image: Project Structure]

My JavaFX project is working perfectly when build in intelliJ with given base path. But when a create exe and run, it throws exception:

The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: You should load resources from the classpath instead of the file system path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219294/104891.

Comment: I am using xlsx file in resources. Can you please write a line of code for accessing this file using classpath

Comment: `getClass().getResource("filename.xlsx");`

Comment: Its giving this error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\M%20Junaid\Desktop\Xlsx.exe!\Borrowers.xlsx (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)