# com.apple.eawt - what exactly I should install

Tags: java, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using Max OS X Mountain Lion, java -version returns  "1.6.0_37". But I cannot compile project with com.apple.eawt.* classes imported.

What I have to install to have Apple Java Extensions on my system?

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**:

I receive following error from compiler:

```
java: package com.apple.eawt does not exist
```

**Update-2**:

XCode version 4.5.2 is installed

**Update-3**:

The reason of my problem was missed ui.jar in classpath. Thanks to @Ian Roberts

Comment: It would help if you clarified the question. Do you need the com.apple.eawt classes, or are you asking whether you need them?

Comment: I believe he wants to use the classes, but cannot compile when he tries to import them.  I could be wrong, tho...

Comment: @jahroy is right. I cannot find out how to build a project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no JAR to download or anything extra to install, the classes are part of the JDK on Mac OS X.  In Apple Java 6 JDKs they live in `Contents/Classes/ui.jar` under the JDK bundle (e.g. `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk` or `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk`), on Oracle Java 7 they are in `lib/rt.jar` under the JRE home directory (`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` or `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0*.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`).

Comment: Thank you! Ui.jar was missed in classpath.

Comment: how to add this to maven compiler plugin? i am new to maven can you please help me.

Comment: @Mubasher if you're compiling on a Mac it should work out of the box, if you're not on Mac then you either need to write your code to make the necessary calls by reflection ([example](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/tags/release-8.0/src/main/gate/gui/MainFrame.java#l1721)) or compile against a stub jar with no-op implementations of the relevant methods, such as http://ymasory.github.io/OrangeExtensions/

Comment: @IanRoberts yeah i am compiling over Mac, compilation of source files failed and specifically on the class where i am using the aewt.Application code. i tried to add dependency by manually extracting rt.jar file from JDK home/jre directory. now this way it is working

Comment: This helped me decompile some old software. I used the rt.jar found in `jdk1.8.0_261.jdk` on Big Sur.

Comment: on Big Sur, look for /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

Answer (score 5):

## Solution for Java 9 and later

> In JDK 9, internal APIs such as those in the Mac OS X com.apple.eawt package will no longer be accessible.

see: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/272

`com.apple.eawt` has been replaced.
Some of the features are covered here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Taskbar.html

An example implementation of setting the dock icon in mac os can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924202/5276779

Comment: Not all of the com.apple.eawt features appear in the java desktop, it's not really been replaced totally. If you want access to the gestures from the touchpad you need com.apple.eawt.event, which is hidden away, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535595/what-replaces-gestureutilities-in-java-9 on how to get them working.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're still looking and anyone else hits this, the MacOS GestureUtilities are still available for that platform. See [What replaces GestureUtilities in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535595/what-replaces-gestureutilities-in-java-9)

Answer (score -1):

Just like any other external library, you have to add the JAR containing those classes to your classpath. Just because you are running on a Mac does not mean the stock Java JDK is 'extended' -- otherwise, it would not be truly platform-independent.

Comment: Could you please provide me a link or at least a google search request to get a URI to download such JAR? I cannot find it.

Comment: That's not actually true.  The JDK that apple makes available for a Mac does have some extensions built in.  Most of apple's extensions are concerned with either making the GUI work more like native Mac apps (like com.apple.eawt and com.apple.laf) or interfacing with QuickTime (quicktime.*)

Comment: How to do this for gradle? dependency to 'com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:1.4' does not seem to work

Comment: I found out: for gradle add this dependency: compile fileTree(dir: '/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes', include: 'ui.jar')