# How to make Java app appear in Mac OS X dock with an icon

Tags: java, macos

I finished a program, and it has an icon. When I double click on the .app, it appears in my dock as a java app, not using the icon I chose for it. I am on snow leopard. How do I make it so that the icon I choose for it is the one on the dock?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006173/how-do-you-change-the-dock-icon-of-a-java-program ... googled 4 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Does your Info.plist (in the Application Bundle) specify an icon?  For example:

MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>myicon.icns</string>
```

And does your .app contain the icon?  For example:

```
MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/myicon.icns
```

Comment: My Info.plist does specify an icon, and OS X sees it in Finder with that icon. However, when I open it on the dock, it has the default 
Java app image.

Comment: CFBundleIconFile is the "legacy" way to do it, according to the Apple docs now. However, they don't explain how to do it the "new" way! ARggg