# How would I show app badge notifications on Mac? *Java*

Tags: java, macos

I am creating a messaging program and I would like to know how I would add an app badge notification on a mac?  (You know, the numbers that appear on the app's icon in the dock)

Comment: Are you using Swing or JavaFX or SWT or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077936/java-mac-add-notifications-to-the-dock-icon-1-2-etc