# How do I get the Dock icon to appear for a Clojure app on a mac?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

Currently nothing (not even the java coffee cup) appears.

I created my app using `lein new reagent name` and I've tried these jvm options:

```
java -Xdock:name=Name
     -Xdock:icon=/Users/bmaddy/Downloads/logo.jpg
     -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true
     -Djava.awt.headless=false
     -jar name.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that just using [Seesaw](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw) does something that makes the dock icon appear. That's good enough for what I need.

```
(ns name.server
  (:use seesaw.core)
```

Other stuff I tried:

The automator method described here only gave an icon to start the app and it didn't stick around while it was running:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4805123

There's some good ideas here, but I wasn't able to get any of them to work: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191609/how-to-create-a-app-folder-from-an-executable-jar

Building an `.app` package from scratch led to a bunch of `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810` errors I wasn't able to solve, but that seems like it would be the most correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Java interop ?
Following this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006173/how-do-you-change-the-dock-icon-of-a-java-program) question :

```
// let's translate this
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
...
Application application = Application.getApplication();
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("icon.png");
application.setDockIconImage(image);

// into Clojure
(import com.apple.eawt.Application java.awt.Toolkit)
(let [app (Application/getApplication)
      image (.getImage (Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit) "icon.png")]
   (.setDockIconImage app image)))
```

Comment: The `.setDockIconImage` call returned `nil` so I suspect it successfully changed the image, but I still can't see the icon on the dock.