# JavaFX OSX stage dock icon won't work

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to set an icon for my javaFX application, I tried:

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/path/fileName.png"));
```

and

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(<className>.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/fileName.png")));
```

but both of the options only result in changing my [icon in window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu6EF.png), not the [dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOAE8.png) icon. Is there something else I can try?

Thank you

Java 8, OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006173/how-do-you-change-the-dock-icon-of-a-java-program

Comment: Thank you, but the above solution only changes the dock icon to well known black-green exe icon. I have my image in PNG.