# Open Java GUI using desktop Icon on mac

Tags: java, fxml

I have made a Java Application on Eclipse on my MacBook Pro. The GUI is made using FXML. How do I create an icon on my desktop that I can click and it launches the First GUI Screen of my application? Thanks.

Edit: I want it so that I click on an icon on my desktop, and it immediately launches my program and the first screen of the GUI opens and is ready to go.

Comment: Probably one on the best things you want to do is create a "platform specific application bundle" - See [Self-Contained Application Packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm)

Comment: Before some else tries to tell us that this is a duplicate to [How do you change the Dock Icon of a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006173/how-do-you-change-the-dock-icon-of-a-java-program) - please take the time read and understand both questions - *"How do you change the Dock Icon of a Java program?"* is about changing the icon AFTER the application is launched, this question is about having the ability to display the application icon on the desktop BEFORE it's launched (ie a short cut)