# How can i show my Java Swing program icon on Mac's Force Quit Applications window?

Tags: java, macos, swing, icons, info.plist

When i run my Java Swing application on Mac OS X, then i click <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Options</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> on my keyboard to run the "Force Quit Applications" window, i see my program having a terminal icon.

I have tried using this tag in the info.plist file but it didn't make any difference:

```
<string>-Xdock:icon=../Resources/prog_icon.icns</string>
```

**How can i replace this icon with another one of my own?**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How do you change the Dock Icon of a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006173/how-do-you-change-the-dock-icon-of-a-java-program) If you are using Java 9 or newer then scroll down to the answer about Java9+. The other option is to bundle your jar into a native app using a tool that will correctly show the icons.

Comment: @sorifiend ... I've followed the solution in this question but it didn't show the icon in the Force quit menu!